# Using ActionBar.tabListener

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Implementing a TabListener without creating a new class but from a thing like this:

```
tab.setTabListener(new ActionBar.TabListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String mirror = "www.something.com";

        if (!file.exists()){
            ScaricaLog scarica = new ScaricaLog();
            scarica.execute(mirror, file.toString());
            visualizza(file);
        }
        else {
            visualizza(file);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

How can I retrieve a reference to the Fragment to execute, in onTabUnselected method, ft.remove that reclaim it?
Is it really mandatory to create a Fragment-extended class?

Thanks guys and sorry for mistakes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. `getApplicationContext()`
2. Then `getFragmentManager()`
3. From the manager, you get the Fragment you are looking for either using `findFragmentById(id)` or `findFragmentByTag(tag)`

HTH

Comment: Perhaps do I need to create a Fragment obj with the resource before?

Comment: Yes please. Please make sure that the fragment is created and is running. Look at the Fragment lifecycle.